# Derivative of function $f(z)=z\text{Re}(z)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

The complex function $$f(z)=z\text{Re}(z)$$ has $$f'(0+0i)=0$$
I thought that it's false as this function is not differentiable at $0$ but I'm not so sure now, is there a way to prove that this statement is either true or false?

Comment: You could show whether the function is differentiable or not using the Cauchy-Riemann relations, but here since we're only looking at one point, that's arguably a little overkill. Instead, try using the limit definition of the derivative and see where that gets you.

Comment: If you write your function in terms of $x$ and $y$, it is $f(x,y) = x^2 + ixy$. If the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied at $(0,0)$, then it is complex differentiable there. Recall that complex differentiability is not the same as holomorphicity/analyticity - those require the CR equations to hold on an open set, whereas complex differentiability can hold on any set.

Comment: $\Re(z)$ is indeed no differentiable, but the factor $z$ restores differentiability at $z=0$ (by absorbing the second term of $\Re(z)+z\Re'(z)$).

Answer (score 4):

By definition of the complex derivative we have
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{f(z) - f(0)}{z-0}  = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z\operatorname{Re}(z)}{z} = \lim_{z\to 0} \operatorname{Re}(z) = 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x+iy)=x^2+ixy=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

As $u_x=v_y, u_y=-v_x$ hold at $(0,0)$ along with the comtinuity of $u,v,u_x,u_y,v_x$ and $v_y$ there so $f$ is diffetentiable at origin. The derivative is given by $f'(x+iy)=u_x+iv_x=2x+iy$